# Android set two animation on view programmatically

Tags: android, animation

here I am use this code for make scale animation

```
Animation anim = new ScaleAnimation(1f, 0f, 1f, 0f, b, a);
anim.setDuration(130);
anim.setFillAfter(false);
view.startAnimation(anim);   
anim.start();
```

now my view animation without problem but when i add another animation to it its didn't animate any one and this is my code for make two animation its scale and translate

```
Animation anim = new ScaleAnimation(1f, 0f, 1f, 0f, b, a);
Animation animT = new TranslateAnimation(0f,b,0f,a);
anim.setDuration(130);
animT.setDuration(130);
anim.setFillAfter(false);
animT.setFillAfter(false);
view.startAnimation(anim);   
view.startAnimation(animT);   
anim.start(); 
animT.start();
```

as we can see i cant use both of the animation as same time how can i solve it without use xml animataion because my variable was changed every time

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `AnimationSet` as follows:

```
AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);

Animation anim = new ScaleAnimation(1f, 0f, 1f, 0f, b, a);
Animation animT = new TranslateAnimation(0f, b, 0f, a);

set.addAnimation(anim);
set.addAnimation(animT);
set.setDuration(130);

view.startAnimation(set);
```

Comment: can I change `new ScaleAnimation(1f, 0f, 1f, 0f, b, a);`  values while animate like change `(1f, 0f, 1f, 0f, b, a)` ?

Comment: @medo yeah you can. In fact if you're on Android Studio, click on `ScaleAnimation` text in your code while pressing Ctrl key. This should open up the doc and it will tell you about other constructors of the class too.

Comment: i didnt see any method for change the values while animate did u have an example

Comment: @medo I might be mistaken here but, what exactly do you want to change? The values? As in `1f` to `0.5f`?

Comment: `pivotX` and `pivotY` == _(a ,b)_ if i can change them while animate i will remove translate animation

Comment: @medo They are float values so yeah, they are changeable. Also look at `pivotXType` and `pivotYType`

Comment: I was searching a way to start two animations at once as `ObjectAnimator` was failing under API 24 and this helped me a lot. Thanks, +1.

Answer (score 5):

you need to use `AnimationSet` and add whatever animation type you want to it 
here is an example

```
Animation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
fadeIn.setDuration(1000);
Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
fadeOut.setStartOffset(1000);
fadeOut.setDuration(1000);
AnimationSet animation = new AnimationSet(true);
animation.addAnimation(fadeIn);
animation.addAnimation(fadeOut);
view.startAnimation(animation);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `AnimationSet` to add multiple animation for a View.
Check out this link: [Animation with animationSet() in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355495/animation-with-animationset-in-android)