# How to trigger a certain animation for an image at specific times?

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I have two images side by side I want to animate them to make a pulse like animation. My question is how do I do it so that they alternate between each other as follows:

duration is 8 min---->

- image 1 triggered for 20 sec while image 2 waits
- image 2 triggered for the next 20 sec while image 1 waits
- image 1 triggered again for 20 sec while image 2 waits
- and so on until the 8 min are over.

My issue isn't with the animation itself. It's with triggering the animation at these specific times while my timer is counting down.

Comment: show what you have tried so far

Comment: Well the the thing is I haven't tried because I don't know what methods or tools I'm supposed to use. I've been looking around so far, most of what comes up in my searches involves an alarm. So basically I want someone to point me to the right direction, I'll manage.

Comment: that kind of questions are in fact forbidden, SO is for helping in resolving bugs and weird behavior, not suggesting whole solutions or HOWTOs..

Answer (score 1):

check out `AnimationSet` - you can query multiple `Animation`s in there and every animation can have own start delay, duration, repeat mode etc. check this SO for some [samples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355495/animation-with-animationset-in-android)

or

simply make two `Animation`s for each `View`. start one for 20 secs and attach listener - when it ends then start another anim, and so on. [HERE](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidAnimation/article.html) you can find some overview of animations API

PS. "pulse like animation" seems like `scaleX` and `scaleY` animation

Comment: Ok I'll check it out and I appreciate you responding